# Z-Matrix Generator for Gaussian

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am looking for a way to convert XYZ coordinates into z-matrix for Gaussian input files. I need to specify certain coordinates in the matrix, therefore, the automatic built-in function from gaussview isn't of much help. Do you know of a program that can help me? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [molden](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/) can write z-matrices, you can load in a xyz file and save it as z-matrix

Comment: [Chemcraft](http://www.chemcraftprog.com/) has a very descent built-in constructor of Z-matrices.

Comment: +1 for chemcraft. you can define the coordinates you need and even let the software do the rest.

Answer (score 11):

Try [Open Babel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page), the windows GUI has a lot of features that may be of help depending on what are those specifics you need in your Z-matrix.

Answer (score 9):

[Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/), nice, clean and very user friendly.
Just draw the molecule, then navigate to menu *Extensions → Gaussian*.
Here you can format and select z-matrix for Gaussian input.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comment by [Fl.pf](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/37142/fl-pf), the program [molden](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/) has a very powerful ZMAT Editor:

- You can hand pick the atoms that define bond lengths, angles and dihedrals
- You can save as: GamessUS, GamessUK, Gaussian z-mat, mopac, xyz

If you want to convert back to xyz with [obabel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page) (for example after replacing a variable in the zmat with a range of values), use mopac (mopin in obabel).

Molden takes a bit to get used to, but this task can be done quite well there.

Comment: direct description molden z-mat: http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/zmat/zmat.html ; open babel xyz: http://openbabel.org/wiki/XYZ_(format) ; Redefining a z-matrix from an automatically produced one in molden is a bit of nightmare though

Answer (score 6):

Gaussian provides all you need to do this with the [newzmat](http://gaussian.com/newzmat/) program.
It literally does all this, no need for 3rd party software.

I found it works best to put the Cartesian coordinates in a file by themselves and save it as `xyz`, then in the command line just run (Note the atom types need to be in front of the coordinates so

i.e. `C   XXXX YYYYY ZZZZZ` would be one line in the file if your first atom was carbon)

```
newzmat -ixyz name_of_xyz_file
```

It will output `name_of_xyz_file.com` in z-matrix format.

Comment: This is not particularly useful to those that cannot afford Gaussian, and certainly not to those of us who are unable to use it because we are developers of other codes.  It would be nice to add to your answer that this is a commercial program with a restrictive license.

Comment: Sorry but the question is implicitly involves Gaussian. This answer is quite useful.

Comment: I appreciate that perspective but I stumbled on this looking for a generic solution for z-matrices (other codes accept formats that are trivially difference from Gaussian’s) and the other responses were quite useful to this end.

Comment: +1 to them then. I already gave them my +1. I think it is crazy to add clauses to answers. Should I advertise your software as well? Gaussian bad, X good. Let me know what X is.

Comment: X is any software that’s accessibly to anyone reading StackOverflow.

Comment: Isn't gausview using this exact tool to built the z-matrix in the first place? The one tool that the user didn't find helpful in some cases. Nevertheless, I think you're quite correct for most cases, like generally. / While I agree that it would have been nice to say that Gaussian is a commercial software, that job would have been the OPs job as they tailored the question specifically to it. @JeffHammond